# What is the difference between numpy.array() and numpy.copy() while copying an array?

Tags: python, numpy, copy

```
a = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)

b = np.array(a)

c = np.copy(a)
```

Is there an important difference? If `np.array(a)` is good enough, then what is the purpose of `np.copy` method?

Comment: If you call `np.array` with `copy=True`, it's the same. If you call it with `copy=False` then it's not the same (sometimes). (also `np.copy` just does `np.array(..., copy=True)` under the hood)

Comment: `copy=True` is the default @CJR, so given the OP's code you are saying it's the same?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.